# getElementsByClassName + onclick на элемент полученной коллекции

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при клике в браузере на слова "просто", "средне", "сложно" в div с классом result вставлялось значение + значение дата атрибута. Сейчас при клике на элемент выводятся все значения сразу, а нужно только того элемента на который кликнул.

```
<div class="toggle" data-value="3">
  Просто
</div>
<div class="toggle" data-value="6">
  Средне
</div>
<div class="toggle" data-value="9">
  Сложно
</div>

<div class="result">

</div>
```

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');

function func() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].getAttribute('data-value') !== undefined ){
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML + elems[i].dataset.value;
    result.appendChild(p);
  }   
    }
}
elems[0].addEventListener('click', func);
elems[1].addEventListener('click', func);
elems[2].addEventListener('click', func);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

for(let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  // Развешиваем событие клика на элементы
  elem[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Записываем в result содержание блока и его data атрибут
    result.innerText = `${this.innerText} - ${this.dataset.value}`;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle" data-value="3">
  Просто
</div>
<div class="toggle" data-value="6">
  Средне
</div>
<div class="toggle" data-value="9">
  Сложно
</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @MaxAkinshin к слову, если именно такие значения дата- будут использоваться везде, то их вообще можно убрать и заменить на `(i + 1) * 3`